# The value provided for the report parameter 'InserviceDate' is not valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)

Tags: ssrs-2008

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lX4Zw.png)

I have an SSRS Report that uses five (5) parameters. When the user selects the first parameter in the report, the subject error occurs.  The report errors before allowing the user to enter the parameter that is causing the failure.

The easiest countermeasure would be to provide a default date for the parameter, but it would have negative and unintended consequences with some of the other report parameters.

Ideas?

Comment: As the error states not valid type. Your parameter InserviceDate suggest it is date type, now what type of parameter is this in your report could you check that?

Comment: Stored Procedure: @InserviceDate datetime = null
Report Parameter: [@InserviceDate] = Date/Time